# MongoDB data wiped when space runs out

Tags: mongodb

I am having occassions where I run a background downloading job on my server, disk space runs out, and MongoDB shuts down. When I start it again, it doesn't allow me to, until I clear up some space, and offers me a --dbpath and --smallfiles option to alleviate the pain. After I get the server up again, I find that my previous records are all gone, and I have no idea where my database files were stored before.

Answer (score 0):

The default db path is /var/lib/mongodb, so you can start MongoDB again with mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb and --smallfiles and --fork --log-path nameoflog.log and it should work fine.

Comment: Sure. If you happen to be running ubuntu or a similar debian distribution. Different distributions use different locations. All of which are generally stored in `mongod.conf ` or `mongodb.conf` depending on the version. A `ps -ef | grep mongod` will at least tell your where the `--config` file is located or other start options used on the process. Not really a useful self answer here, and not a programming topic either.